# Plot the fitness of a genetic algorith. How to access object values inside a function

Tags: python, function

I have a genetic algorithm that is designed for dicovering a string with 7 letters, with 20 individuals in each population and 600 generations.

I want to create a plot that graphs the mean of the fitness for each generation

The first thing I decided to do is to create a list that stores the mean for each generation, so then I can plot it later.

```
def initialize_population():
    population = []
    for i in range(0, GENES):
        adn = [random.choice(string.printable[:-5]) for _ in range(0, len(desired_string))]
        fitness = obtain_fitness(dna, desired_string)
        candidate = Individual(dna, fitness)
        population.append(candidate)
    return poblacion
```

This function above calls for different functions, to obtain fitness value, etc, and creates a population (list) of candidates, each with a dna (string) and a fitness. This function above is inside another function called simulation, which executes the script.

What I want is to get the fitness value for each candidate, but I didn´t manage to do that.

```
progress = []
for i in range(0, MAX_GENERATION):
    progress.append(numpy.mean(sum(candidate.fitness[i])))
```

But this gives me the error:

```
NameError: name 'candidate' is not defined
```

As you can see, `candidate` was defined in the initialize_population function, but I don´t know how to call it.

Comment: There is substantial information missing without which it's impossible to locate the error. Please provide an [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

first of all it seems like your function returns `poblacion` which i dont see defined anywhere in the function, I will assume it is a typo.
since you are creating candidate in a loop `GENES` times, even if you make candidate global, if you call it after the function is done you will only get the final one you assigned.

Im assuming you already call the function as

```
yourlist = initialize_population()
```

then you can access the candidate you want by `yourlist[i]` where `i` is the index you want.
But Im still not sure if your candidate will have an attribute `.fitness` unless you defined it for that object in the rest of your  code.
I hope this makes sense

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're missing is the proper variable scope.

The function above `initialize_population()` can't see `candidate`.
To make it visible use `global` keyword before initializing `candidate` inside `initialize_population()`. The drawback of this solution is that it will only let you see the last candidate.

```py
def initialize_population():
    population = []
    global candidate
    for i in range(0, GENES):
        adn = [random.choice(string.printable[:-5]) for _ in range(0, len(desired_string))]
        fitness = obtain_fitness(dna, desired_string)
        candidate = Individual(dna, fitness)
        population.append(candidate)
    return population
```

Anyway, I don't think accessing `candidate` is correct in your case. All candidates are already in `population` list, so try accessing them with that.